# How do I override the Share/Email/Save as Attachment in Excel 2013 with a custom macro

Tags: vba, excel

We have recently upgraded from Office 2003 to Office 365.

I used to override the `File/Send` feature with a macro that would check whether the current file was a confidential company file (by name). If it was then it would block the send. If it wasn't then it would open an email with the file attached.

```
Sub sendme()
    aName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Flag = True
    If InStr(UCase(aName), "CONFIDENTIAL FILE") Then Flag = False
    If Flag = False Then MsgBox "You are trying to email " + aName + ".  This action has been blocked.", vbCritical: End
    Mail_with_outlook
End Sub

Sub Mail_with_outlook()
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strto As String
    Dim strcc As String
    Dim strbcc As String
    Dim strsub As String
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    If InStr(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, "\") = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please save workbook before continuing", vbCritical
        End
    End If


    strto = ""
    strsub = ""
    strbody = "Special signature"

    With OutMail
        .To = strto
        .CC = strcc
        .BCC = strbcc
        .Subject = strsub
        .Body = strbody
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .Display
    End With

End Sub
```

How do I do the same thing in Excel 2013 - to override the `Share/Email/Save as Attachment` in Excel 2013 with a custom macro ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is impossible. The only thing possible seems to me to be is to add the code functionality to a button on an addin, and ask the users to use this button to send the email